# MapView change colors

Tags: android, android-mapview

Is there a way to change the colors used in a MapView?
My app has very specific design in terms of used colors and uses different shades of grey, white and black and the MapView looks a bit odd. Is there a way to somehow change the colors it uses to display everything(roads, rivers, mountains etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Google Maps you can use switch to different layouts like satellite http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-google-map-switching-between-map-view-and-satellite-view/

But if you want to change a lot, e.g. using only darkgrey and white for ur mapView, u might replace your google MapView and use OSMdroid OpenstreetMapView instead. Functionalities are nearby the same (in compare with Google Maps V1 ). 
There you can override the onDraw method

OSMDroid https://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/